# Extract json in an array in Jmeter

Tags: java, json, regex, jmeter, jsonpath

How do I extract the json object `name` from the below `json data` in **Jmeter**

```
[
:   {
:   :   "name":"x",
:   :   "age":"50",
:   :   "gender":"Female"
:   }
]
```

I am doing this `$..name` in the JsonPath Extractor which is giving me this in the variable I extracted to

```
name=["x"]
```

Is there a way I could just get `name=x` without the array format

Or is there a way I can extract just the `x` from `["x"]`?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try via the index? `$..name[0]`

Comment: yes, that's not extracting anything

Comment: Then, try `${name_1}` after getting the array with `$..name`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - yeah, using String newName= vars.get("name_1"); in the beanshell post processor is giving me `newName` as just `x` but when I am trying to use `newName` in other requests by passing as `${newName}` it is  being passed as  `${newName}` only but not it's value `x`

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be passed as `${__V(${newName})}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That didn't work . So tried this which didn't work as well `${__V(Var${newName})}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ${name_1} works. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
 ${name_1}
```

after getting the array with

```
$..name
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this in a bean shell post processor worked

```
 String newName = vars.get("name"). replace([","").replace("]","").replace("\"","");
log.info("name is: " +newName);
```

which gives `name is: x`

Answer (score 2):

You need to get **name** attribute from the **first** object in the array therefore you need to amend your JSON Path expression to look like `$[0].name`

References:

- [JsonPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)