# How to use array from response1 in request2 in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract a jsonArray from response of request1 and use it in request2. I am using JSONextractor the steps in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396250/extract-json-in-an-array-in-jmeter#) but I am getting the array as different variables instead of 1 jsonArray.

My JsonExtractor:

[image: Json Extractor]

Output of debug sampler:

[image: Debug sampler output]

Request:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "asd"
    },
    {
        "id": "def"
    },
    {
        "id": "hij"
    }]
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong that is extracting values in different variables instead of 1 jsonArray.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a JSON request body from the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are coming from the JSON Extractor using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

1. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the request which you want to parameterize
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def payload = [:]

   def items = []

   1.upto(vars.get('userIds_matchNr') as int, { index ->
       items.add([id: vars.get('userIds_' + index)])
   })

   payload.put('items', items)

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. You should be able to put the `${payload}` JMeter Variable reference into the request "Body Data" tab

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you. Some minor tweaking to the script and it worked but why is it extracting in different variables in the first place? Is this a new feature in Jmeter or are my settings wrong for json extractor?  From what I found online I should be able to extract json array directly using JSON extractor.